# dynamic path in form partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, partials

How would I go about using a dynamic path in a form partial that can be set to different paths depending on which page I'm calling the form partial in?

for example, in my _form.html.erb file, at the bottom, I would like to be able to dynamically change the 'cancel' path depending on which page im calling it on:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
    <%= form_for(@chef, :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form" }) do |f| %>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :chefname %>
        <%= f.text_field :chefname, class: "form-control", 
                                placeholder: "Chef Name", 
                                autofocus: true %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control", 
                                 placeholder: "Email" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control", 
                                 placeholder: "Must be at least 5 characters" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password_confrimation, "Confirm Password" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confrimation, class: "form-control", 
                                 placeholder: "Confirm Password" %>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit "#{action} Account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      </div>

    <% end %>

    <%= link_to "Cancel", cancel %>

    <hr>

    <% if logged_in? && (current_chef == @chef || current_chef.admin?) %>
      <%= link_to "Delete Account", chef_path(@chef), method: :delete, 
                                     class: "btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger",
                                     data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this account and all corresponding recipes?" } %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in the new.html.erb where I'm calling it, I try to set 'cancel' to a path.

```
<%= render "form", action: "Create", cancel: root_path %>
```

What would be the proper way to do this? It seems to work in my browser, but then in my test I get undefined local variable or method 'cancel'.

```
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined local variable or method `cancel' for #<#<Class:0x00000001da1e38>:0x0000000322cf10>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're very close. You just need to specify `cancel` as part of the `locals` to get it through to the partial:

```
<%= render "form", action: "Create", locals: { cancel: root_path } %>
```